# How to capture a process Id and also add a trigger when that process finishes in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, triggers, background-process

I am trying to make a bash script to start a jar file and do it in the background. For that reason I'm using `nohup`. Right now I can capture the pid of the java process but I also need to be able to execute a command when the process finishes.

This is how I started

```
nohup java -jar jarfile.jar & echo $! > conf/pid
```

I also know from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/345455) that using `;` will make a command execute after the first one finishes.

```
nohup java -jar jarfile.jar; echo "done"
```

`echo "done"` is just an example. My problem now is that I don't know how to combine them both. If I run `echo $!` first then `echo "done"` executes immediately. While if `echo "done"` goes first then `echo $!` will capture the PID of `echo "done"` instead of the one of the jarfile.

I know that I could achieve the desire functionality by polling until I don't see the PID running anymore. But I would like to avoid that as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bash util `wait` once you start the process using `nohup`

```
nohup java -jar jarfile.jar &
pid=$!     # Getting the process id of the last command executed

wait $pid  # Waits until the process mentioned by the pid is complete
echo "Done, execute the new command"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get around "polling until you don't see the pid running anymore." `wait` is a bash builtin; it's what you want and I'm certain that's exactly what it does behind the scenes. But since Inian beat me to it, here's a friendly function for you anyway (in case you want to get a few things running in parallel).

```
alert_when_finished () {
  declare cmd="${@}";
  ${cmd} &
  declare pid="${!}";
  while [[ -d "/proc/${pid}/" ]]; do :; done; #equivalent to wait
  echo "[${pid}] Finished running: ${cmd}";
}
```

Running a command like this will give the desired effect and suppress unneeded job output:

```
( alert_when_finished 'sleep 5' & )
```